# python regex to find text between headers

Tags: python, python-re

Consider the text:

> HEADER
> the cat
> HEADER
> the dog
> HEADER
> the bird

Using python attempting to construct a regex to extract the text between each HEADER section.

I have tried:

```
results = re.findall(r'HEADER([\s\S]+)(?:HEADER||$))
```

This ends up capturing all the text in the capture group.

Assumption was the above regex would capture all text between to header blocks, or a header block and the end of file

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `split`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that in that specific case using a .split("HEADER") is easier then a regex. Do you specifically need a regex for some resason?

Comment: Argh. Thank you. Forgot about split.